# proguard cant find javax.servlet

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I'm finally attempting to run proguard for my android app but I get the following error about 20 times.

```
org.apache.thrift.server.TServlet: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.*
```

From what I can tell from googling is I have to add servlet.jar to my list of -libraryjars.

The thing is none of my code references this package and it compiles fine even though I don't have servlet.jar in my build path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The org.apache.thrift library is referencing javax.servlet. If your app works without it anyway:

```
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**
```

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)